# Need help understanding mergeSort and apply()

Tags: javascript, apply

I'm new to js and I'm trying to understand how `apply` is used here (I've been struggling with trying to understand `apply` as of late). However, my issue is *two-fold*. While I understand the overview of mergesort, but I have no idea what is happening in the last block.

```
function mergeSort(items){

    if (items.length < 2) {
        return items;
    }

    var middle = Math.floor(items.length / 2),
    left    = items.slice(0, middle),
    right   = items.slice(middle),
    params = merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));

    // Add the arguments to replace everything between 0 and last item in the array
    params.unshift(0, items.length);
    items.splice.apply(items, params);
    return items;
}
```

Comment: where is `merge`? without seeing what it spits out it's hard to explain. it's a splice sig no doubt, but how?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the values in *params* are to be used as arguments when calling *splice*. If there were say 3 members, the call would be:

```
items.splice(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
```

but since it's not known beforehand how many members there will be and hence what the call should look like, *apply* allows the arguments to be passed as an array. Now you don't need to know how many there are:

```
items.splice.apply(items, params);
```

so the call is effectively:

```
items.splice(params[0], params[1], params[2], ..., params[n]);
```

*apply* also allows setting of *this*, and since that should be *items*, it's passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

`apply` is almost the same as `call`.

If you understand `call`, `apply` is just `call`, but the second argument is an array of arguments. For example, these are the same:

```
function.call(object, arg1, arg2, ...)
function.apply(object, [arg1, arg2, ...])
```

I am not sure what you don't understand in the last block. But I assume is this part `items.splice.apply(items, params);`

Here's a breakdown. In js, functions are just objects. And objects can have functions, (or instance methods, as in many other OO language).

When you do `items.splice`, all you are doing is just reach into `items`, then pull the `splice` function out (as an object). Then you use `apply` to invoke it. The first argument of `apply` is the object that you invoke on. In your example, `items` in the parenthesis is the one that calls `splice` function, `params` is an array of arguments.